# How to pass data from main activity to fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

i am a newbie in android development. I am now seeking a solution on how i can pass a value from main activity to different fragments. My apps have a main activity and 5 fragments. I would like to do xml parsing in my main and then pass processed data to different fragments so that i can draw different pages at the same time. My main has set a new fragment adapter

mAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

And then in my FragmentAdapter (which extend FragmentPagerAdapter and implements IconPagerAdapter), i have overwrite the getItem method so that i can create 5 fragment to handle 5 different pages.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = new Fragment1();
    switch(position){
    case 0:
        fragment = new Fragment1();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new Fragment2();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new Fragment3();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new Fragment4();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new Fragment5();
        break;  

    }
    return fragment;
}
```

My question is how i can pass some value from my main to the newly generated fragments.For e.g i would like to pass a value "A" from my main to fragment 1. How can i do this task? Tks in advance for your help!~

Answer (score 0):

Tony, in the link http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

```
ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
newFragment.setArguments(args);
```

The above code snippet allows the MainActivity to pass an int data to the ArticleFragment class.

ArticleFragment class then can use code snippet below to read the int data in say its onCreate method.

```
int position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);
```